# How to read / visualize a .vtk file in Python, (using Jupyter)?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, vtk, mayavi

I have a .tvk file, wanted to visualize it in Python using Jupyetr.
I can use the mayavi to see the file.
However, I wanted to know is there any way to visualize the file without using the mayavi.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Pyvista to read/visualize VTK files: https://docs.pyvista.org/api/readers/_autosummary/pyvista.VTKDataSetReader.html?highlight=vtk#pyvista.VTKDataSetReader